# jsf set errors when i connected to workbench

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, mysql-workbench, javabeans, eclipse-jee

I'm new to java ee and I'm trying to make my first website using java ee but I find a lot of difficult when i want to connect my jsf to workbench I have also a problem with serialization because i have always to generate the serial of beans manually

this it my beans
Userbean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@Named /*("userBean")*/ 
@RequestScoped
public class Userbean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1043069413653729199L;

private String iduser="";
private String username="name";
private String password="0000";
private String email="";
private String city="";
private String country="";

public Userbean() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Userbean(String iduser, String username, String password, String email, String city, String country) {
    super();
    this.iduser = iduser;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.city = city;
    this.country = country;
}

public String getIduser() {
    return iduser;
}

public void setIduser(String iduser) {
    this.iduser = iduser;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String returnAction2() {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    String query ="INSERT INTO `jee`.`user`( `username`, `email`, `password`, `city`, `country`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    boolean a=false;
    try {
        ps= Myconnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setString(1,username);
        ps.setString(2,email);
        ps.setString(3,password);
        ps.setString(4,city);
        ps.setString(5,country);


        if(ps.executeUpdate()>0){
        a=true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
        a=false;
    }

    return a==true ? "success" : "failure";
}
```

}

this is my view **sign up**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<f:view>
    <head>
        <title>Login screen</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>sign up</h1>

        <h:form>

            username: 
            <h:inputText id="username" value="#{userBean.username}" />
            <br/>

            Password:
            <h:inputSecret id="password1" value="#{userBean.password}" />
            <br/>
             email:
            <h:inputSecret id="email" value="#{userBean.email}" />
            <br/>
             city:
            <h:inputSecret id="city" value="#{userBean.city}" />
            <br/>
             country:
            <h:inputSecret id="country" value="#{userBean.country}" />
            <br/>



            <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.returnAction2}" value="Connect" />

       </h:form>
    </body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: Either use `@ManagedBean` **or** `@Named` (preferring the latter.) Please add a focused description of your problem (one per posted question only) and add a [mcve]

Comment: Your question is vague. It's like you're going to a garage with your car and telling that your car is broken, but you didn't tell what exactly is wrong with your car. Please post any errors/exceptions you have seen. These represent the answer to your problem.